# Unit Testing ReactNative with Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I am searching for how can I implement unit testing feature in my app but there are limited resources are available , Is there any documentation available which provide step to step guide on adding Unit testing feature in ReactNative app.

Coz most of the document are outdated as one says we need to mock react-native and there import react/addons which was is not available now.

Now there is no add ons file in React....

Answer (score 2):

I would follow the official Jest [docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html#content) to set up the testing environment with `react-native`.

There should be no difference with testing Redux/reducers. For components, you can use the new [snapshots](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html#snapshot-test) testing methodology which is also compatible with `react-native`. You can see a small example in the Jest repo: https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/examples/react-native.

Comment: Nerge thanks for yr reply , I can create a snapshot of the class in __tests__ directory and also the snapshot of yr class need to be changed when yr class is modified But what if you want to test some function and what if your class calls another class in render with props and create UI in that particular class.

Comment: I think you need to create a question with the test you are trying to do that does not work (try first to do it) and post the code into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a while back, the docs aren't complete awesome on unit testing with React Native, but here's how I handle a test on a method for a component, which is probably most of what I use.

Here's a typical example in Jest:

```
it('handles onInputTextChanged', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<TuraltChat isAnimated={false} />);
  wrapper.instance().onInputTextChanged("The message has changed");
  expect(wrapper.state("text")).toBe("The message has changed");
});
```

The `instance()` method exposes the underlying component, and you can then call methods on it in the usual way.

Even though it's annoying in all the DOM dependencies, I'm also using enzyme, which helps a lot for component-level tests, because I don't need to worry about all the nested components.

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';

...

it('renders initially', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Composer />);
  const json = toJson(wrapper);
  expect(json).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```